# Use find command to extract lines from text files in subfolder

Tags: awk, find

I have text file `input.txt` in each of the hundred subfolders named `sample_1, ..., sample_100`.

I can extract first line of all `input.txt` files using below command:

```
find -name input.txt -exec awk 'FNR == 1 {print $0}' > out.txt {} \;
```

But this prints the first line of all `input.txt` to one `out.txt` file in the current directory.

What I want is `out.txt` in each subfolder with first line of `input.txt` in that particular subfolder. For example, `out.txt` inside `sample_57` subfolder will have first line of `input.txt` in `sample_57`.

Any idea on how to get this done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
find . -type f -name "input.txt" -execdir awk 'NR==1{print $0>"out.txt"}' '{}' +
```

Or you can use `exit` handler, which it will exit after print first line and better when you only want to print first line and not required `awk` to process whole file till the end of it.

```
find . -type f -execdir awk '{print $0>"out.txt";exit}' '{}' +
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `head` instead of `awk`. Also, use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to make the command to execute easier to read.

```
find -type f -name input.txt -execdir sh -c 'head -1 input.txt > out.txt' \;
```

Answer (score 5):

> `out.txt` in each subfolder with first line of `input.txt` in that
>   particular subfolder

**`find`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name input.txt -exec sh -c 'out_fn="${1%/*}/out.txt"; sed -n "1p" "{}" > "$out_fn"' _ {} \;
```

- `out_fn="${1%/*}/out.txt"` - path to *output filename* in format `/path/to/subfolder/out.txt`
- `sed -n "1p" "{}"` - extracts the 1st line from the input file `{}`